# Flink job manager goes down cannot find root cause

Tags: apache-flink

We are using Flink 1.13.1 on a kubernetes HA pod cluster we are pointing to a Minio instance and saving checkpoints externally to the buckets

Every so oftern the job manager fails with the following error and we cannot trace the root cause

```
2023-03-30 13:11:12,538 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Fatal error occurred in the cluster entrypoint.
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Application failed unexpectedly.
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.lambda$runApplicationAndShutdownClusterAsync$0(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:170) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$WaitingConjunctFuture.handleCompletedFuture(FutureUtils.java:905) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.JobStatusPollingUtils.lambda$pollJobResultAsync$4(JobStatusPollingUtils.java:91) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$0(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:234) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:1079) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:263) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:73) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:644) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:205) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:328) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:279) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:283) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:235) [flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Invocation of public default java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.RestfulGateway.requestJobStatus(org.apache.flink.api.common.JobID,org.apache.flink.api.common.time.Time) timed out.
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Invocation of public default java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.RestfulGateway.requestJobStatus(org.apache.flink.api.common.JobID,org.apache.flink.api.common.time.Time) timed out.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.$Proxy43.requestJobStatus(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.13.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.JobStatusPollingUtils.lambda$getJobResult$0(JobStatusPollingUtils.java:57) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.JobStatusPollingUtils.pollJobResultAsync(JobStatusPollingUtils.java:87) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.JobStatusPollingUtils.pollJobResultAsync(JobStatusPollingUtils.java:69) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.JobStatusPollingUtils.getJobResult(JobStatusPollingUtils.java:56) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.getJobResult(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:286) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.lambda$getApplicationResult$3(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:271) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.getApplicationResult(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:272) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.lambda$runApplicationAsync$2(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:221) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.runApplicationEntryPoint(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:254) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.lambda$runApplicationAsync$1(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:212) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ActorSystemScheduledExecutorAdapter$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ActorSystemScheduledExecutorAdapter.java:159) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:44) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://flink/user/rpc/dispatcher_1#-1969347872]] after [60000 ms]. Message of type [org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.LocalFencedMessage]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$2.apply(AskSupport.scala:635) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$2.apply(AskSupport.scala:635) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:648) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
        ... 9 more
2023-03-30 13:11:12,543 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Shutting StandaloneApplicationClusterEntryPoint down with application status UNKNOWN. Diagnostics Cluster entrypoint has been closed externally..
2023-03-30 13:11:12,544 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                     [] - Stopped BLOB server at 0.0.0.0:6124
2023-03-30 13:11:12,544 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.MiniDispatcherRestEndpoint [] - Shutting down rest endpoint.
```

This is our HA file setup

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  JOBMANAGER_OPT_ARGS: ""
  KAFKA_GROUP: *****
  KAFKA_PORT: *****
  KAFKA_SERVER: ******
  flink-conf.yaml: |
    jobmanager.rpc.address: *******
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 3
    blob.server.port: 6124
    jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
    taskmanager.rpc.port: 6122
    queryable-state.proxy.ports: 6125
    #queryable-state.enable: true
    jobmanager.memory.process.size: 2048m
    taskmanager.memory.process.size: 4096m
    fs.overwrite-files: true
    client.heartbeat.interval: 30000
    execution.checkpointing.tolerable-failed-checkpoints: 10
    execution.checkpointing.unaligned.enabled: true
    web.timeout: 1000000
    akka.ask.timeout: 30000
    log4j.logger.akka: INFO
    log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka: INFO
    log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper: INFO

    ### HA
    ## HA - NOTE Flink auto creates dynamic configaps in default namespace using below cluster-id unless you specifiy namespace like below
    kubernetes.cluster-id: *******
    kubernetes.namespace: ******
    high-availability: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory
    ## HA - Using Nutanix Files Server
    #high-availability.storageDir:*******
    ## HA - Using MinIO
    high-availability.storageDir: *******
    presto.s3.access-key: *******
    presto.s3.secret-key: *******
    presto.s3.endpoint: *******
    presto.s3.path.style.access: true

    # Fault tolerance and checkpointing
    state.backend: filesystem
    #state.checkpoints.dir: *******
    ## - Using Nutanix Files Server
    #
    #state.savepoints.dir: *******
    ## - Using MinIO
    state.checkpoints.dir: *******
    state.savepoints.dir: *******
    state.checkpoints.num-retained: 10
    parallelism.default: 3
  log4j-console.properties: |
    # This affects logging for both user code and Flink
    rootLogger.level = DEBUG
    rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = ConsoleAppender
    rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFileAppender

    # Uncomment this if you want to _only_ change Flink's logging
    logger.flink.name = org.apache.flink
    logger.flink.level = DEBUG

    # The following lines keep the log level of common libraries/connectors on
    # log level INFO. The root logger does not override this. You have to manually
    # change the log levels here.
    logger.akka.name = akka
    logger.akka.level = DEBUG
    logger.kafka.name= org.apache.kafka
    logger.kafka.level = INFO
    logger.hadoop.name = org.apache.hadoop
    logger.hadoop.level = INFO
    logger.zookeeper.name = org.apache.zookeeper
    logger.zookeeper.level = INFO

    # Log all infos to the console
    appender.console.name = ConsoleAppender
    appender.console.type = CONSOLE
    appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
    appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n

    # Log all infos in the given rolling file
    appender.rolling.name = RollingFileAppender
    appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
    appender.rolling.append = false
    appender.rolling.fileName = ${sys:log.file}
    appender.rolling.filePattern = ${sys:log.file}.%i
    appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
    appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n
    appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
    appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
    appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
    appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
    appender.rolling.strategy.max = 10

    # Suppress the irrelevant (wrong) warnings from the Netty channel handler
    logger.netty.name = org.apache.flink.shaded.akka.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
    logger.netty.level = OFF
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-21T11:43:26Z"
  labels:
    app: flink
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: *******
  name: ******
  namespace: ******
  resourceVersion: "******"
  uid: *******
```

We are trying to repoduce the error but are currently making no headway

- tried to make minio inaccessable but its not affecting the dispacher
- tried to throttle the system but its handeling the requests so long
- we played with the slots and resources allocated

We cannot seem to repoduce the errors and the jobmanager just drops randomly every now and then